# Vim: Is there a downside to using <Space> as your <Leader> key?

Tags: vim

I recently started using `<Space>` as my mapleader, and I find it very comfortable and fast. I can slap that key with either thumb, freeing up whichever hand I need for the next keystroke, and even one-handed combos are pretty easy. I'm curious why I haven't heard more Vim users recommend this. Is there a downside I'm missing? I see a lot of people recommending `,` but that feels awkward to me for a lot of combos.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446269/can-i-use-space-as-mapleader-in-vim

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I use space as my leader and love it. I've found that for me, (with their default actions) `,` is occasionally useful and `<space>` is literally never useful.

I can't think of any downsides to the spacebar,* and likewise have no idea why `,` is so apparently common.

* Except for one easily-solvable one. Space doesn't appear for `'showcmd'`. I work around this by using `\` as my leader and mapping (must be `:map`, not `:noremap`) space to `\`.

Comment: Nice workaround! I'm going to try this.

Comment: It's not working for me. The mapping works, but `showcmd` doesn't show `\` when I hit `<Space>`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm... Here's the minimal version of what I did. `map <Space> <Leader> ** nnoremap <Leader>x i ** set showcmd`. (replace the `**`s with newlines since comments have to be one line) Use that as your `vimrc`. Does it work? On my machine, I'm able to use `<space>x` as `i`, and \ appears when I hit the spacebar.

Comment: I tried it again, and it seems to work if I start a new Vim session. I tried to isolate it but couldn't figure out what was interfering. Anyway, it works now. Thanks!

Comment: Found the tip for `'showcmd'` helpful. One problem I ran into which I wasn't able to come up with a work around for was with that mapping it didn't seem possible to invoke keybindings mapped to `<leader><leader>[key]`

Comment: Space does appear as <20> in the "showcmd" for me. (I'm using gVim for Windows version 7.4, patches 1-1965)

Comment: @pandubear What do you like <space>x as i? It seems longer, although it is left handed.

Comment: @rodarmor It was just an example for debugging ivan's problems.

Comment: Could you add the full vimrc code that you use rather than just the instructions?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't take long to get used to `,` (compared to the default `\` anyway). However, given that most people map their leader-key to `,`, some plugins ([nerdcommenter](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter) for example) are written with this in mind and using `<Space>` may interfere with some functionality. If you can live with that, go for it.

Comment: When having space as the leader doing <space>c<space> still works for toggling the comments, so it doesn't seem like an issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have been comfortable using `;` as the leader. It helps the fingers stay on the home row and has been easy enough to use. But now, `space` seems to be a good option too. It doesn't conflict with my workflow. I'll probably give it a try.

Comment: You should definitely ditch `;` for `space`. `;` is the command for "jump to next `f/t`-result. I find it very useful.

Comment: I haven't used `f` or `t` a lot. So, `;` has worked for me all along. Using `space` instead of `;` will be the first thing I'll try after the holidays.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why I've never heard anyone else use `<space>` for mapleader. It makes sense to me as long as you don't use `<space>` for navigation, which I don't either. I can't think of any other disadvantage.

Comment: Insert mode mappings with leader will cause a delay on each space press. That's the only I have found as I had one insert mode mapping but as I can live without it I have simply removed it.